# I am getting an error "expected a member name" on the "lbldisplay" code line building a calculator

Tags: c++

I'm getting this error:

> expected a member name" on the "lbldisplay"

Here's my code snippet:

```
System::Void button9_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {        
        firstnum = Convert::ToInt32(lbldisplay->Text);    
        lbldisplay-> = "0";
        operation = '-';
}
```

Could you guys help me?

Comment: something should come right after `lbldisplay->` and before  `= 0;`

Comment: lbldisplay->Text = "0";

Comment: Change `lbldisplay-> = "0";` to `lbldisplay->Text = "0";`. The member is missing.